I accidentally plated DH5a E. coli and left them in the 4℃ for 12 hours, if I put them into the 37℃ incubator will they start growing?
I started ligation of my constructs late last night and was super tired, since I used all of my ligation mixture I would rather not have to re-ligate.
I did my transformation procedure as follows:

Thaw on ice
Add 5 µL of ligation mixture and mix
Leave on ice for 30 min
Heat shock at 37℃ for 5 minutes
Add 500 uL of LB broth and mix
Incubate at 37℃ for 30 minutes
Spin down at 5000 rpm for 5 minutes and remove supernatant to re-suspend in 100 µL of LB broth
Plate on ampicillin agar plates with glass beads

Made a really dumb mistake and left them in the 4℃ instead of 37℃ overnight. Is this salvageable?

Go ahead and try it. Wat do you have to loose? My guues would be that it shouldn't natter.

If these were just regular E. coli that you were growing up, then it wouldn't matter too much - they would certainly grow a lot slower on the plate than you might otherwise expect compared to a plate put in the incubator straight after plating. The inhibitory cold and dry in the fridge means that they tend not to survive as well as they do after normal incubator growth and then storage.
However, as these are transformants and you only did a short recovery step of 0.5 h (~1 replication cycle), there's a good chance that you have lost the plasmid, so is quite likely that you won't get much growth because you have a selective ampicillin. I would be dubious about any that do grow as to whether they have the plasmid or not.
Much better to make a fresh ligation and try again after some rest.
